# How display media's date in Wordpress/php

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I try to search some solutions on Stackoverflow for my problem but I don't find anything.

I would like to display date when a media was uploaded on Wordpress, I use page templates with many php code. I try to do it with some functions but it doesn't work.

Comment: can you show us what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this function:

```
// retrieves the images date from the file URL
function rustys_get_image_date($image_url) {
  global $wpdb;
  $attachment = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE guid='%s';", $image_url )); 
  $id = $attachment[0];
  echo get_the_date('F j, Y g:i a', $id);        
}
```

The use it with:

```
<?php rustys_get_image_date("full image url here")  ?>
```